# Spring Security OAuth2 Behind a Proxy Server

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

There seem to be many examples of Spring Security OAuth2, but most of them run on localhost at some specific set of ports. I was able to get my application working with ports specified for my AuthorizationServer and my ResourceServer. The next step I needed to take was move this application behind a proxy server, but the application stopped functioning. The main issues seem to be path related, but I'm struggling with lack of examples on how to accomplish the task of moving OAuth2 Spring behind a proxy server. I've focused on overriding the WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint, but I'm not sure if this is what is required.

I was able to create a controller that is nearly identical to the WhiteLabelApprovalEndpoint, but do not know how to adapt it to accommodate being behind a proxy.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
public class ApprovalEndpoint {

    @RequestMapping("/oauth/confirm_access")
    ...
        private static String TEMPLATE = "<html><body><h1>OAuth Approval</h1>"
        + "<p>Do you authorize '${authorizationRequest.clientId}' to access your protected resources?</p>"
        + "<form id='confirmationForm' name='confirmationForm' action='authorize' method='post'><input name='user_oauth_approval' value='true' type='hidden'/>%csrf%%scopes%<label><input name='authorize' value='Authorize' type='submit'/></label></form>"
        + "%denial%</body></html>";
    ...
```

The only change I made to the class was to update the form action string, making the path relative by replacing

```
action='${path}/oauth/authorize'
```

with

```
action='authorize'
```

This allows the POST to go to the correct URL

```
http://localhost/proxy/stuff/javaPath/oauth/authorize
```

instead of

```
http://javaPath/oauth/authorize
```

The latter doesn't map when submitted through Apache (the frontend proxy). But it would seem that this creates other problems in the Java application, because this results in the error

```
error="invalid_request", error_description="Cannot approve uninitialized authorization request."
```

I see that this exception is thrown in the AuthorizationEndpoint when the authorizationRequest is null. This looks like it should be handled by my custom class having SessionAttributes set properly, but updating the just the path that I'm POSTing to seems to break this.

Answer (score 0):

May be you already solved it but posting the answer as it may help someone.

It is because authorize end point URL (domain + path(including proxy)) should be consistent. I mean either it should be 'localhost' or your proxy path but it should be consistent.

As OAuth uses session internally and later fetches it from the same path (when the POST happens) . So if the URL changes (POST) it wont get the session then it throws **Cannot approve uninitialized authorization request.**

For my case ,I was using the authorize end point as:

```
https://mydomain/myapp/oauth/authorize?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=clientid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8181&response_type=code
```

but in the properties I was having :

```
server: 
  session: 
   cookie: 
    path: /appProxy 
  context-path: /myapp
  port: 8081
```

After successful authorization when POST  is done on   it tries to fetch the session from `/appProxy/myapp` instead of `/myapp`  and resulting in **Cannot approve uninitialized authorization request.**

So to solve this, I can either remove Session.cookie.path property or run Oauth server on  `https://mydomain/appProxy/myapp/oauth/authorize` to make it consistent.